Input in a Bootstrap Accordion Header causes the accordion to open close on "click" and "press:space"
I have an input field in a Bootstrap accordion header.
Whenever I click in the input the accordion closes or opens depending on its state. The same happen as I type in the input and I type <Space>. How can I block these?
Here is the markup:
.accordion
  .accordion-item
    %h2.accordion-header
      %button.accordion-button
        .container
          .row
            .col-3
              = level.name
            .col-9
              = hypothesis_form.text_field :description, class: 'form-control'
    %div{ id: "structure-level-#{hypothesis.id}", class: 'accordion-collapse collapse show' }
      .accordion-body
        = render partial: '...', locals: { ...


"I have an input field in a Bootstrap accordion header." - why? That is a very bad idea to begin with. button and input are both interactive elements, and as such must not be nested - otherwise, you are creating invalid HTML. You could try and find workarounds using JavaScript, adding your own event handlers - but I doubt that would fix the usability issues this creates to begin with. If anything, you should take that input field out of the button, and place it before or after it.

After all I removed the input from the accordion and synced the input to the accordion header, so no interactivity is messing up anymore. Thx for the tip.

Please... 1) Tag your Bootstrap version per the instructions on the twitter-bootstrap tag description. 2) Show us actual markup, not whatever script configuration that is. 3) Put your code in a working demo using the editor. Include Bootstrap via CDN.
